# Passing scope variable to "child" controller

Tags: angularjs, variables, controller

I have a controller with

```
$scope.Id = 'something';
```

In html

```
<div ng-include="~[some path]/something.cshtml'" ng-controller="ChildController" id="#{{Id}}" ng-init="Id = Id"></div>
```

In generate HTML, id="#something" is correctly generated.

But in childcontroller,
$scope.Id is 'undefined'.

It looks lik ChildController is initiated before its "parent" conroller. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because `ng-controller` & `ng-include` both does create a new scope which is prototypically inherited from parent.

Use [**`dot rule`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) while dealing with scope hierarchy/inheritance.

```
$scope.data = {Id :'something' }
```

On html you need to use it like

```
{{data.Id}}
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UbFQbTt6IKdJg0h8dXUh?p=preview)

**Edit**

You could not load `.cshtml` file form its path you should have to load it from the ASP.NET MVC controller's action because it can have `C#` content that needs to parse through `C#` view engine before rendering it on view.

Comment: I tried $scope.data = {Id :'something' } in parent scope but then as expected I get "data" as undefined in child scope.

Comment: No problem loading .cshtml.

Comment: @TTT did you removed `ng-init`?

Comment: Now yes. But that did not change anything.

Comment: @TTT could you create a plunkr of it?

Comment: Check plunkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/UbFQbTt6IKdJg0h8dXUh?p=preview which is showing the same

Comment: @TTT could you share me how you loaded `.cshtml` in `ng-include` its interesting to know me

Comment: I can hardly reproduce it in a Plunkr as it's part of a quite complex soultion. I checked with colleagues who did other parts. It turns out my problem comes from the way other controllers are intiated (by something called "template service")